# Google Map not shown when IOS app is in the appstore

Tags: ios

If I install my App over XCode everythings works fine, but if I install the App over TestFlight or the AppStore, the google map is not shown?
Very strange. Does anyone has experiences with that?

Comment: check you have properly import google map sdk or not. In most cases due to this problem arrives. try to run in device with xcode if you don't have import properly then xcode will give error.

Comment: no error in Xcode, I made it with a pod file ...